# Count number of concurring events

Tags: python, bash, awk

This question is related to the previous question linked here [Number of consecutive values above certain cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950646/number-of-consecutive-values-above-certain-cut-off/50958963?noredirect=1#comment88939485_50958963) and slightly with the answer provided by @kvantour

So in my case I have file like this (**Sample Input**)

```
 0.34
  0.3432
  0.32
  0.35
  0.323
  0.3623
  0.345
  0.32
  0.31
  0.378
  0.34
  0.35
  0.342
```

First: In my case if  2 or more consecutive values satisfy a given cutoff c =0.33 I called it B. This is given by condition m see here: [Number of consecutive values above certain cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950646/number-of-consecutive-values-above-certain-cut-off/50958963?noredirect=1#comment88939485_50958963)

Second: if the c is 0.33 and I want values lower than c it will print out 0.32 and 0.323 but I also want to print out 0.35 because that is just one occurrence of above the c which doesn't follow my rule as mentioned in m hence it will also be printed out. This was answered by @kvantour . I called this F

So in my $2 the states look like this `BCBCB`

So I can count number of broken (**B**) events like  following (**Sample Output**)

```
2 #this corresponds to no. of frames in first B 
2 #this corresponds to no. of frames in second B 
4 #this corresponds to no. of frames in third B
```

Is there a way to count and print out no. of broken events as a list?

Comment: It is not clear, could you please post sample of input and expected sample output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: The sample input and output is already there I will edit the question a bit

Comment: Maybe this question is linked with a previous question hence it is tough but can you please point out which part is unclear

Comment: Any suggestions it seems like a tricky one based on my beginner bash or python knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

Determine how many frames in a row are broken. If just one frame is broken (but the previous and next frame are good), that's okay, ignore that. A frame is broken if its value is above the cutoff (0.33).

### A Python solution

```
from itertools import groupby
```

Read in the input

```
def get_input():
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        next(f) # skip the first line
        input_list = []
```

I'm splitting each line based on the space and ignoring the frame number

```
        for line in f:
            input_list.append(float(line.split()[1]))

    return input_list
```

This is a helper function the just returns True or False if the value is above the cutoff

```
def above_cutoff(x, cutoff):
    return x > cutoff
```

Here's the fun part. We are grouping values based on whether they are above or below the criteria. We get back the group and can check how many are in it.

In the `for` loop below, the variable `above` will be `True` if the group is above the cutoff. `g` is a generator containing the group. I just convert it to a list because that's easier to use and check the length of.

```
def count_broken(input_list, cutoff):
    # returns list with number of values in a row above threshold
    state = []

    for above, g in groupby(input_list, lambda x: above_cutoff(x, cutoff)):
        group = list(g)
        print(above, group, len(group))
```

If the group is longer than 1, it meets your criteria so append its length

```
        if above and len(group) > 1:
            state.append(len(group))
    return state

input_list = get_input()
print(*count_broken(input_list, 0.33), sep='\n')
```

The print statements in the loop outputs this:

```
True [0.34, 0.3432] 2
False [0.32] 1
True [0.35] 1 # while this group is True/in state B/broken, ignore it cause it is just 1 frame.
False [0.323] 1
True [0.3623, 0.345] 2
False [0.32, 0.31] 2
True [0.378, 0.34, 0.35, 0.342] 4
```

The final result is:

```
2
2
4
```

I based my solution on the accepted answer from this question: [Take in a list, return a list of True/False based on consecutive duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801616/take-in-a-list-return-a-list-of-true-false-based-on-consecutive-duplicate-value/50801727#comment88609474_50801727)

Comment: so group is the array which saves all this values as satisfy the condition. Is it right? If not how to write a file (column) format which prints out all the values which satisfies my condition?

Comment: `groupby` groups things as to whether they are above your threshold or not. If they are, `above` is `True`. By checking the length of `group` and checking the boolean value of `above`, you can check if this `group` is one you want to do something with.

Comment: To print a column: `a = [1, 2, 3]` and then

`print(*a, sep='\n')`. If the output you need now is different than mentioned in the question, you can edit the question and let me know.

Comment: yes but the script doesnot store the below cutoff values and the single jump values such as 0.32
0.35
0.323
0.32
0.31 as a array so I can't print out them or is there another way to do it. This becomes too complicated hence I posted a fresh question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157677/printing-out-number-of-concurring-events-and-corresponding-values

Comment: I'll answer over there

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue (with friends)

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print ($2>0.33)}' file | uniq -c | awk '$2 && $1>1{print $1}'

2
2
4
```

**Explanation**

> `NR>1{print ($2>0.33)}` print 1 or 0 whether the condition `$2>0.33` is satisfied, skipping the first header line.
>
> `uniq -c` count the consecutive duplicate values (chain length)
>
> `$2 && $1>1{print $1}` print the chain length when the value is nonzero (here it's 1) and length is greater than one as specified by OP.